# Ubuntu won't recognize windows install disc/USB

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have a confirmed working windows 8.1 install disc (Used it to completely install windows 8.1 on another computer with a corrupted windows Vista installation, on which I am typing this question) and the same data on a bootable USB that I have also tested to ensure it was set up properly. I can't get the Ubuntu machine to boot from the disc or the USB, no matter the boot order or BIOS configuration.

After trying countless solutions I could find via this site and many others (nearly all of which hinge on getting a bootable windows disc/USB to work), I installed Ubuntu again via live CD and simply reformatted the partition with Ubuntu on it to NTFS, and I still can't get it to boot from USB or disc, and GRUB doesn't list booting from disc as an option.

Currently working on removing GRUB without needing the machine to recognize a Windows disc using lilo. Edit: getting "cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied". Going to reinstall Ubuntu and try it again.

- The hardware, including the disc drive, hard drive, and USB ports are all in working order.
- I haven't gotten the "press any key to boot from disc" prompt

Comment: Are you able to enter the BIOS setup screen at boot so that you can change the order of the boot devices?  Is this a UEFI computer?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a UEFI machine, tbh. I think it's BIOS. It's a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5300. I do have the boot order set to prioritize both USB and the CD drive over the hard disk currently, however. 

And I have boot speed set to normal so it doesn't automatically boot from the HDD, and secure boot is disabled.

Comment: I am no expert but I had similar problems with a 64 bit UEFI system refusing to boot off any external media.  The boot order setting changes that I made were not persistent.  I had to reboot, enter the BIOS, insert the USB, and change the boot order while the USB was present.  On subsequent reboots it would again ignore the USB unless I entered the BIOS setup every boot.  YMMV

Comment: The boot priority is persisting between restarts, it must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu/grub should not be affecting the boot of the windows installer if the installer is the first thing to boot. You may need to change your boot order in bios.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. I currently have both USB and CD booting before the hard drive currently.